# Retrieving response data from axios post differs from raw response data

Tags: javascript, vue.js, base64, blob, axios

I've been developing a Flask/Vue webapp and I've run into an issue regarding downloading of files. I'm serving a userupload from the backend using flask, which returns a file through send_from_directory(). This is called through a downloadFile method in Vue

```
downloadFile(key, name){

            const path = '/api/ticket/filedownload'
            this.$ajax.post(path, {address: key}, {responseType: 'arraybuffer',})
            .then((response) => {
                // Create response donwload link
                const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response.data], response.headers['contentType']));
                const link = document.createElement('a');
                link.href = url;
                link.setAttribute('download', name);
                document.body.appendChild(link);
                link.click();
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error)
                window.alert("File not found")
            })
        }
```

This method I found online in many places and seems to work for most people.
Yet the file that gets served at the front end "contains errors" or seems corrupt.
In my network tab I can clearly see that the post request was successful and the response is the actual image (e.g.) that was sent! When copying the response from the post result directly in my network tab (Mozilla, right mouse>copy>copy response) I was able to retrieve that the response was base64 encoded and could be decoded easily to the same image that was uploaded. **However!** When printing the response.data, the output is completely different and not in base64:

```
base64 from network tab: R0lGODlhWAJYAvcAABAQEL2cUntSG(etc...)
console.log(response.data):GIF89aX�X���������R{R�)�1)�1�j ���������ޔ��{)��j
```

I have tried supplying the response.data as a blob directly or by parsing it in a filereader to no avail. Our this.$ajax.post is a workaround for axios' post, which can be supplied with returnTypes such as blob, arraybuffer, text, anything, all with the same result. 
My question is: How would I go ahead and access the response such as it was displayed in the network tab as I am capable of converting from base64, not an unknown format. Or how would I parse this response in any successful way.

Comment: I have the same issue, the file saved from axios response.data has EF BF BD literals (Unicode fallback)